# Prime numbers which can be written as sum of the squares of two numbers x and y

Tags: python, algorithm, primes

The problem is:

Given a range of numbers `(x,y)` , Find all the prime numbers(Count only) which are sum of the squares of two numbers, with the restriction that `0<=x<y<=2*(10^8)`

According to [Fermat's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) :

```
Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares asserts that an odd prime number p can be   
expressed as p = x^2 + y^2 with integer x and y if and only if p is congruent to 
1 (mod4).
```

I have done something like this:

```
import math
def is_prime(n):
    if n % 2 == 0 and n > 2:
        return False
    return all(n % i for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2))

a,b=map(int,raw_input().split())
count=0
for i in range(a,b+1):
    if(is_prime(i) and (i-1)%4==0):
        count+=1
print(count)
```

But this increases the *time complexity* and *memory limit* in some cases.

Here is my submission result:

[image]

Can anyone help me **reduce the Time Complexity and Memory limit with better algorithm**?

[Problem Link](http://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/primeman-1/)(Not an ongoing contest FYI)

Comment: The question on hackerearth.com is confusing. In the text they initially talk about two sets `S1`and `S2`, later they completely forget about them. What numbers are in these sets? How do you get them because they don't seem to be part of the input? How can you known that `x` is in `S1` and `y` in `S2` without knowing them?

Comment: Confirm the indentation in your code paste please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not check whether each number is prime. Precompute all the prime numbers in the range, using [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). This will greatly reduce the complexity.

Since you have maximum of 200M numbers and 256Mb memory limit and need at least 4 bytes per number, you need a little hack. Do not initialize the sieve with all numbers up to `y`, but only with numbers that are not divisible by 2, 3 and 5. That will reduce the initial size of the sieve enough to fit into the memory limit.

**UPD** As correctly pointed out by Will Ness in comments, sieve contains only flags, not numbers, thus it requires not more than 1 byte per element and you don't even need this precomputing hack.

Comment: 1565024(Kib) that is nearly 200MB it fails. I think limit is much less

Comment: This value is from the link to problem posted by OP. Less memory - more numbers to check manually before initialization, doesn't matter.

Comment: Four bytes per number in the sieve of Eratosthenes? To serve as a prime/composite marker?

Comment: @WillNess You're right, my glitch. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce your memory usage by changing `for i in range(a,b+1):` to `for i in xrange(a,b+1):`, so that you are not generating an entire list in memory.

You can do the same thing inside the statement below, but you are right that it does not help with time.

```
return all(n % i for i in xrange(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2))
```

One time optimization that might not cost as much in terms of memory as the other answer is to use [Fermat's Little Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test). It may help you reject many candidates early.
More specifically, you could pick maybe 3 or 4 random values to test and if one of them rejects, then you can reject. Otherwise you can do the test you are currently doing.

Comment: Yes you are correct :) but time limit still a problem.

Comment: surely for such a wide ranges sieving should be much much faster than testing?

Comment: @WillNess, I agree, but he is dealing with both memory and time constraints, and using fast probabilistic primality testing might be enough to get through his time constraint without getting limited by memory.

Comment: not very likely, not when testing whole ranges of numbers.

Comment: @WillNess, Please elaborate. I am very curious about this, because my thought was that if you can speed up a bunch of the individual tests within the range (by rejecting early), then you can speed up the entire computation.

Comment: how fast is this probabilistic testing? how many operations per number (in, say, equivalent divisions)?

Comment: @WillNess, I have not benchmarked modular exponentiation in Python, so I cannot give you a specific number, but it would be the (cost of modular exponentiation) * (small constant).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, although it will not change the **order** of your time-complexity, you can still narrow down the list of numbers that you are checking by a factor of 6, since you only need to check numbers that are either equal to `1 mod 12` or equal to `5 mod 12` (such as [1,5], [13,17], [25,29], [37,41], etc).

Since you only need to **count** the primes which are sum of squares of two numbers, the order doesn't matter. Therefore, you can change `range(a,b+1)` to `range(1,b+1,12)+range(5,b+1,12)`.

Obviously, you can then remove the `if n % 2 == 0 and n > 2` condition in function `is_prime`, and in addition, change the `if is_prime(i) and (i-1)%4 == 0` condition to `if is_prime(i)`.

And finally, you can check the primality of each number by dividing it **only** with numbers that are adjacent to multiples of 6 (such as [5,7], [11,13], [17,19], [23,25], etc).

So you can change this:

```
range(3,int(math.sqrt(n))+1,2)
```

To this:

```
range(5,math.sqrt(n))+1,6)+range(7,math.sqrt(n))+1,6)
```

And you might as well calculate `math.sqrt(n))+1` beforehand.

To summarize all this, here is how you can improve the overall performance of your program:

```
import math

def is_prime(n):
    max = int(math.sqrt(n))+1
    return all(n % i for i in range(5,max,6)+range(7,max,6))

count = 0
b = int(raw_input())
for i in range(1,b+1,12)+range(5,b+1,12):
    if is_prime(i):
        count += 1
print count
```

Please note that `1` is typically not regarded as prime, so you might want to print `count-1` instead. On the other hand, `2` is not equal to `1 mod 4`, yet it is the sum of two squares, so you may leave it as is...

Comment: your `is_prime(n)` tests `n` by all the 6-coprimes below its `sqrt`, potentially, but surely it can be evenly divided only by its factors?

Comment: @Will Ness: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. It tests a given `n` with 5,11,17,23,29,35... and with 7,13,19,25,31,37,... below or equal to `sqrt(n)`. This should be enough for every `n` which is not divisible by 2 or 3.

Comment: it is much more than enough, was the point I was trying to make. :) the complexity of testing a range up to `n` that way is `O(n^1.5)`, but for the sieve of Eratosthenes the complexity is `O(n log(log n))`. I.e. very very much faster, for such wide ranges.

Comment: @ Will Ness: I only suggested an improvement to the current implementation (as given in the question). Doesn't the sieve mean that you have to maintain an array which indicates prime/composite for every number, in which case you get space-complexity of `O(n)`, which is quite a lot when `n=200000000`?

Comment: you only have to have primes up to sqrt(2*10^8) < 15000, about 1700 primes in total. then, working by segments is entirely possible and even advisable.